# Unable to perform any scaffolding in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Whenever I try to create a controller or view, basically anything but a class I receive the following error.

There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1 is outside of the acceptable range of [0,2147483647]. Parameter name: value'

It's a brand new ASP.Net MVC 4.5.2 app that I have only changed the connection string and modified the individual user accounts to use roles. I attempted deleting everything in the Obj and Bin folder then cleaning and rebuilding the solution with no success. I tried to create a new project and copy over only the files I changed with no success.

[image: Error]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: That looks like a bug in their scaffolding code.

Comment: I'd start by shutting down VS completely, maybe even do a reboot, then reopen VS. If that doesn't work then I'd just kill the project and start over.  You said you haven't changed much so you won't lose much time.